# Xamarin Forms Android PayUMoney Integration Error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, payment-gateway, payumoney

I have the following:-
1. Xamarin form (ContentPage) with a button "Pay"
2. Droid project: PaymentGatewayActivator.cs which has the following code for PayUMoney payment gateway integration:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.PaymentGateway);
            webviewPayment = (WebView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.webView1);

            webviewPayment.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webviewPayment.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);
            webviewPayment.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
            webviewPayment.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
            webviewPayment.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
            webviewPayment.Settings.CacheMode = CacheModes.NoCache;
            webviewPayment.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            webviewPayment.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
            webviewPayment.AddJavascriptInterface(new PayUJavaScriptInterface(this), "");  //JavaInterface

            Java.Lang.StringBuilder url_s = new Java.Lang.StringBuilder();
            url_s.Append("https://test.payu.in/_payment");    //PauMoney Test URL        
            Log.Info(TAG, "call url " + url_s);

            PayUMoneyGateway gateway = new PayUMoneyGateway();
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(gateway.GeneratePaymentPOSTForm());
            webviewPayment.PostUrl(url_s.ToString(), data);

            webviewPayment.SetWebViewClient(webViewClient);
        }
```

Following is the test hash_string:-

gtKFFx|a03e56bd50459806c84e|25|testproductServices|myFirstName|testemail@gmail.com|eCwWELxi

And the actual hash returned by gateway.GeneratePaymentPOSTForm()

edffe24d30100e7042e1af788d21db94ee97e76ee851f004c9815b291c355459f9b0423f3509002824c0adb09e5f3979d1c1916faa0e705ee37ed74a5b99c58d

I am getting following error:
Error Reason:
Invalid Amount

[Check error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NLQK.png)

Answer (score 0):

https://logeshpalani.blogspot.com/2020/07/xamarin-forms-payumoney-integration.html

this blog will help you todo this payumoney integration over WebView not using Xamarin. Because, there is no official SDK for Xamarin

Comment: Based on the URL of your link being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you must disclose that it's your site in your post. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).